# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React'

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to run an existing React project that I found on Github. I've had some issues. First, I needed to update React to v 16.2.0 to get `React.Fragment` working. Now, having done the update, I'm getting this second issue:

```
./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in '/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/DH2642/Sentify/repo/Sentify/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
```

from the console:

```
index.js:2178 ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/getNextDebugID' in '/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/DH2642/Sentify/repo/Sentify/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__   @   index.js:2178
handleErrors    @   webpackHotDevClient.js:178
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage  @   webpackHotDevClient.js:211
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @   eventtarget.js:51
(anonymous) @   main.js:274
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage   @   main.js:272
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @   emitter.js:50
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @   websocket.js:35
```

1. What is the reason for this bug?
2. How to fix it?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

[image]

Here is the project home folder. Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Sentify",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^5.5.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dom": "0.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.7.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.44.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-d3-basic": "^1.6.11",
    "react-d3-core": "^1.3.9",
    "react-d3-shape": "^0.3.25",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.0-rc.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-simple-pie-chart": "^0.5.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

I'm creating the node_modules folder by typing `npm install` and hosting with `npm start`.

I removed node_modules and ran `npm install; npm start` again, and the error changed slightly to:

```
./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in '/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/DH2642/Sentify/repo/Sentify/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
```

in console:

```
index.js:2178 ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/getNextDebugID' in '/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/DH2642/Sentify/repo/Sentify/node_modules/react-dom/lib'
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__   @   index.js:2178
handleErrors    @   webpackHotDevClient.js:178
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage  @   webpackHotDevClient.js:211
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @   eventtarget.js:51
(anonymous) @   main.js:274
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage   @   main.js:272
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @   emitter.js:50
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @   websocket.js:35
```

Additional stack trace from console:

```
ReactDebugTool.js:14 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook"
    at webpackMissingModule (ReactDebugTool.js:14)
    at Object../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDebugTool.js (ReactDebugTool.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactInstrumentation.js (ReactInstrumentation.js:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js (ReactReconciler.js:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdates.js (ReactUpdates.js:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ChangeEventPlugin.js (ChangeEventPlugin.js:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js (ReactDefaultInjection.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js (ReactDOM.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object../node_modules/react-dom/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object../src/index.js (discover.js:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at fn (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:88)
    at Object.0 (welcome.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:678)
    at ./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports (bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:724)
    at bootstrap f031d93a2683340d518f:724
```

Comment: I can say compatibility issues, can you let me know which GitHub project you upgraded the version to React 16.2.0.

Comment: The github project is this one: https://github.com/NiekBijman/Sentify . Please note that I've also removed the node_modules folder in my screenshot and re installed React for the project. That way I didn't need to upgrade React, but the problem persists!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your case it is clearly react and react-dom packages incompatibility.
Make sure that your react and react-dom packages have the same version to avoid incompatibility.

`package.json` now:

```
...

"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^15.6.2", 

...
```

`package.json` with compatible react-dom and react packages:

```
...

"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0", 

...
```

Since [react-v0.14-beta-1](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/07/03/react-v0.14-beta-1.html) react and react-dom are separate libraries and you are supposed to use the same version.

> For now, please use the same version of react and react-dom in your
>   apps to avoid versioning problems — but we plan to remove this
>   requirement later. (This release includes the old methods in the react
>   package with a deprecation warning, but they’ll be removed completely
>   in 0.15.).

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you do not specify that `.js` is a resolvable extension in your Webpack configuration.

When Webpack looks for `./lib/React`, it won't look for the `./lib/React.js` file if, for example, you only specify `.ts` as a resolvable extension.

[Source](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3397#issuecomment-264023168)

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when you update yours react version but not react-dom version.

So, always make sure react and react-dom version should be the same in package.json

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects, I was using lerna for mono-repo and had alias entries for react, react-dom. I removed the aliased and it worked out for me.